# ZOS/Unix cob2 compiling and executing

Tags: unix, cobol, zos

I'm starting with Cobol on ZOS/Unix.

My  environment is terminal via SSH to ZOS machine.

I have Cobol program hello.cbl with basic code to display message.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. "HELLOWORLD".
       AUTHOR. PIOTR SYNOWIEC.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.


       DATA DIVISION.
       
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-PROCEDURE.
           DISPLAY "**************************************************"
           DISPLAY " *** Hello World"
           
           STOP RUN.
       END PROGRAM HELLOWORLD.
```

Program compiles easily with GnuCobol & IBM Cobol compiler on Linux and I can easily execute compiled program.

I tried the same on ZOS/Unix using flag "RENT" as per description here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=services-running-cobol-programs-under-zos-unix

**cob2 -v hello.cbl -o hello.exe**

Compiler messages

```
compiler: ATTCRCTL PARM=RENT,TERM /u/ibmuser/TIPS/tests/basic/hello.cbl
linker: /bin/c89 -o hello.exe -e // hello.o
```

Running program

```
./hello.exe
```

Message

```
Killed
```

Tried with -q64

**cob2 -v -q64 hello.cbl -o hello.exe**

Compiler messages:

```
compiler: ATTCRCTL PARM=RENT,TERM,LP(64) /u/ibmuser/TIPS/tests/basic/hello.cbl
linker: /bin/c89 -o hello.exe -Wl,LP64 -e // hello.o
 IEW2480W A711 EXTERNAL SYMBOL CEELLIST OF TYPE LD WAS ALREADY DEFINED AS A
          SYMBOL OF TYPE LD IN SECTION CELQLLST.
 IEW2482W A712 THE ORIGINAL DEFINITION WAS IN A MODULE IDENTIFIED BY DDNAME
          SYSLIB.  THE DUPLICATE DEFINITION IS IN SECTION CEEBLLST  IN A
          MODULE IDENTIFIED BY DDNAME SYSLIB.
FSUM3065 The LINKEDIT step ended with return code 4.
```

running result is the same: Killed

Could anybody help me to sort that out ?

Answer (score 1):

this solved the problem **STEPLIB=IGY630.SIGYCOMP**

Comment: RENT is a default when compiling with `cob2`. Also if you’re going to use copybooks you need to export the path to them: `export SYSLIB=$SYSLIB:/pathto/copybooks`.